# QGIS Wien 2.8.1 RuntimeError concerning the sip module on Win 7

Tags: qgis, installation, python-2.7, windows-7, sip

I am running windows 7 64bit and python 2.7.9
I just installed QGIS Wien 2.8.1 and it crashes on start up with the following code:

```
Couldn't load PyQGIS.
Python support will be disabled.


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\__init__.py", line 36, in 
    from qgis.core import QgsFeature, QgsGeometry
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\core\__init__.py", line 3, in 
    from qgis._core import *
RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v11.0 to v11.1 but the qgis._core module requires API v10.0


Python version:
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

QGIS version:
2.8.1-Wien 'Wien', exported
```

Comment: how do you run qgis? a win qgis installation (standalone or osgeo4w) has it's own python interpreter and related sip. You probably running qgis ins a way miching pythonpath and PATH (LD_LYBRARY_PATH) in a way that th dynamic loader found the previous installed sip library instead of that packaged with qgis....

Comment: It sounds like it reports an error, not like it crashes.

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn it was crashing after reporting the error, i.e. after the error it didn't just showed an error message. Anyways the fix below resolved it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had set pythonpath to my default python 2.7.9 installation in the environment variables.
i.e i had PYTHONPATH = path/to/python/site-packages

Removing this resolved the issue.